# Access 2013 Web App Cascading Combobox

Tags: ms-access-2013

I am trying to create a cascading combobox. I have read on the internet that you should be able to very simply use the "Parent Control" on the combobox's "Data" button. But I don't have that control on the data button. I've also read about using a query built directly on the combobox to run in the browser and not on the web. But I'm uncertain as to what that means. I see no build button or anything in the combobox's data button. Can anyone help? Was this something that came out after the app's release that not everybody has? I'm lost. Please, help if you can. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that ["Parent Control" is not available in on-premises SharePoint and and only available in SharePoint Online](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-other_msftoffice_apps/cascading-comboboxes-in-access-web-apps-sharepoint/4cbe06fc-9f0b-4dbe-9927-46a44751c935/?auth=1). This may be your issue.
In any case there is a simple 3 minute test to see if you can use cascading combo boxes or not:

1. Create a new Access Web App;
2. Open the App in Access;
3. Create a new blank table and add just one short text column (I called it "Test_name"), save the table as "Test_table";
4. Edit the List view of Test_table and add a new combo box;
5. Open the combo box's "Data" menu and select Test_table as the Row Source.

Now the "Parent Control" property should have appeared at the bottom of the list of properties for the "Data" menu (see the image).  If it hasn't, it means this feature is not available to you.

[See diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymiyE.jpg)

Comment: So sorry about the late reply, here. I left the site for a while after not getting any feedback. Yes, I did that test (and again according to your instructions) and I don't have that control at the bottom. And I am working "On-Premise." So that must be it. Thank you for your reply!